# Use a combination router/modem as a slave to another router

Tags: router, dhcp

I've got a combination cable modem/router from my cable company.  I've also got a [Netgear N900](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/WNDR4500.aspx) that I love.  I'd like to use the advanced features of the N900 (partitioning, guest networks, print server).  I think I have to chain the units together, but I'm guessing I need the N900 to act as the DHCP server in that setup (I'm assuming that the advanced features rely on DHCP).

I can easily hook up my N900 as the slave device (disable DHCP, change IP), but I couldn't figure out a way to go the other way around, where my combo unit gets DHCP disabled and a static IP assigned to it.

Is this possible with a combo unit, to have it act as a slave?

It's a Cox combo unit (maybe a 'Netgear DOCSIS 3.0 11-N Router'?).

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic post.  Do you know if there is a way I can transfer this question to SuperUser?

Comment: You might be able to double-nat it, if the router has an 'internet' port.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no problem with this configuration. Draw a cable from a LAN-side port of your modem/router to the WAN-side port of your Netgear N900. Leave DHCP on, allow the Netgear to get an IP address on its WAn side by means of the modem/router DHCP. Make sure the two internal networks (that of the modem/router and that of the Netgear) are distinct, otherwise your Netgear will be puzzled when it gets a request to forward a packet to a given address, since it will not know whether the address is on the WAN or on the LAN side.

You may pick, as the LAN side net of the Netgear, something unusual, like 192.168.211.0/24, which will come in handy if you want to set up a VPN, or if you need to connect to one.

Lastly, make sure all of your devices go through the Netgear router, so they belong to the same subnet, and they are all visible to each other. Your Netgear router will be the only client of the modem/router.

Turn everything off, then on, starting with the modem/router, then the Netgear router, then the other devices on your LAN. That's it.

Comment: What does "Make sure the two internal networks are distinct" mean?

Comment: @TylerDeWitt It means that one should be, say, 192.168.10.0/24, while the other one should be 192.168.57.0/24, that is, in plain English, that they should cover distinct, **non-overlapping** ranges.